# Executing Javascript scripts after pasting HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, tags

I'm doing some experiments, and I found that when you execute that code on any web pages :

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Javascript scripts just get 'disabled'. So here is a little script I wrote that re-execute those scripts using jQuery ( so you'll need to inject jQuery on some websites ( I'm using Firebug + FireQuery )) :

```
// Disabling all javascript scripts
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

// Saving scripts tags and his parent
var scripts = [];
jQuery('html').find('script').each(function(){
    scripts.push([jQuery(this),jQuery(this).parent()]);
}).remove(); // REMOVING ALL SCRIPT TAGS

// Re-appending those deleted script tags in the right place
for (var i in scripts) {
    scripts[i][1].append(scripts[i][0]);
}
```

So this script works on most of the website I tried, except one : [**Google**](http://www.google.com/) ( in Firefox )

The thing I'm actually trying to do is storing Google HTML, and pasting it into an iframe ( via Firefox Extension ). So everything is working well except that I can't get the Javascript scripts working ( no autocomplete, buttons are not working... ). Here are the errors i get :

> gapi.loaded_0 is not a function
>
> window.google.pmc is undefined

I was thinking that, this may be due to an execution order issue or something. But how can I fix that. Is there any other way to re-run Javascript scripts ? Or any better way doing what I'm doing ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is a better way to do what you are doing.

First, what is happening:

When you use `innerHTML` the existing elements removed from the DOM.  Not quite in a 'burn and salt the earth' because other references might survive, but they are off the DOM.

Fortunately, there is an easy way to deal with this:

This is a wonderful discussion of [Event Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) that describes what you need to do.  It's worth reading to understand behind the scenes.

Once you have that, look at the jQuery's [Event Delgation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) which does a bunch of work for you:

Since you didn't show any HTML, I'll invent some:

```
<div id="contents-will-be-replaced">
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>


// Attach to the DIV
// But listen for buttons
$( "#contents-will-be-replaced" ).on( "click", "button", function() {
  alert("Button pushed");
});
```

Comment: You must have misunrderstood me. My problem isn't the event that trigger the innerHTML. The problem is: I store the Google homepage HTML. And when I try to paste that HTML in an iframe, the javascript scripts won't execute. That's why I wrote a script that remove, and re-append those <script> tags, which is working with any other website except for Google. I didn't show any HTML, because there is not any HTML, except the Google one.

Answer (score 0):

U can simply use Jquery's `.html()` to load a script dynamically in the dom. Basically, jquery will inspect your html when it added to the DOM and then create a script tag in the head automatically. It's pretty slick. See if it works for you.

[From the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

`By design, any jQuery constructor or method that accepts an HTML string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — can potentially execute code. This can occur by injection of script tags or use of HTML attributes that execute code (for example, <img onload="">). Do not use these methods to insert strings obtained from untrusted sources such as URL query parameters, cookies, or form inputs. Doing so can introduce cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. Remove or escape any user input before adding content to the document.`

Comment: The thing is, when I use `$.html()`, jQuery strips my `<head>` and `<body>` tags ( but keeps their children ), so everything is mixed and won't work.

Comment: It makes sense it would strip `<body>` and `<head>` tags since JQuery probably assumes those to be in DOM already. When I used `.html()` to solve a similar issue I was having I noticed that the script tags were not blocking like they would be in the normal DOM render; in other words it seemed to add the scripts async. So in your code you probably need to listen for an `onLoad` event from the script tag before you apply your next script to the DOM.